# Jquery using scrollTop() to fade elements in when scroll bar is at Xpx

Tags: jquery

How do I get an element to fadeIn when you have scrolled X amount of pixels?  Is it something along the lines of?

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 740) { 
        $("#myelement").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Ideally it would fade in only when the scroll bar is between 740px and 1481px. Otherwise it fades out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
var $myelement = $("myelement"); // cache jQuery object

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 740 && $myelement.is(":hidden")) {
       $myelement.fadeIn();
    }else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 740 && !$myelement.is(":hidden")) {
        $myelement.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tiny problem... It doesn't fade in if you click a link that scrolls you to an anchor.  You have to physically scroll to trigger the fade in.  Do i have to add a click function for the button as well? or is there some clever workaround...

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems just fine, really. I put together a fully working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SLpWy/1/), complete with fade in/fade out, though it doesn't really add much other than fleshing it out.